# react-native nested StackNavigator passing parameters

Tags: react-native

I initially had this routing set up below with a tabNagivator and I was navigating to the 'Home' route and passing parameters using:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{station:e,code:f,filter:'',filterName:'',offset:0});
```

Routing:

```
const PrimaryNav = TabNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: LaunchScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        swipeEnabled: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({
            tintColor
        }) => ( <
            Image source = {
                require('../Images/trains.png')
            }
            style = {
                [styles.icon]
            }
            />
        ),
    },
},
Map: {
    screen: MapScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({
            tintColor
        }) => ( <
            Image source = {
                require('../Images/locationTab.png')
            }
            style = {
                [styles.icon]
            }
            />
        ),

    },
},
}, {
headerMode: 'none',
tabBarPosition: 'top',
animationEnabled: true,
tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
    indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: '#33b2f4',
        borderBottomWidth: 3,
    },
    style: {
        backgroundColor: '#000', // Makes Android tab bar white instead of standard blue
        paddingTop: 5,

    }
},

});
```

What I now want to do is replace 'LaunchScreen' in Home route with a stackNavigator but I don't know how to now pass the parameters to the stackNavigator down to the 'LaunchScreen':

```
const FeedStack = StackNavigator({
    Launch: {
        screen: LaunchScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },

    },
    Tweets: {
        screen: TweetScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Service Tweets',
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#000'
            },

        },
    },

}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Launch',
}

);

const PrimaryNav = TabNavigator({
Home: {
screen: FeedStack,
navigationOptions: {
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarIcon: ({
        tintColor
    }) => ( <
        Image source = {
            require('../Images/trains.png')
        }
        style = {
            [styles.icon]
        }
        />
    ),
},
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by navigating to the route and storing the parameters in my mobX store bypassing the navigation parameters altogether.